# Dokku remove worker without finishing tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, worker, dokku

I have Ruby on Rails app and after I do any deployment with Dokku, I have my old worker running the tasks normally, but when I complete the deploy, after a few seconds this worker is removed and a new one is created without finishing all the tasks that were running. Does anyone know how I get around this? Or that the worker finishes all tasks before removing, or when a worker is created after deploying, the tasks from the old worker go to the new worker? Any indication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with a workaround, I created a check_worker.rb file that I call in the predeploy, it silences the workers so as not to take any more tasks, and while there is a worker with tasks being executed, it does not advance with the deploy until it completes all, only after completing all the tasks it completes the deploy

app.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dokku": {
      "predeploy": "ruby check_worker.rb"
    }
  }
}
```

check_worker.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/api'
ps = Sidekiq::ProcessSet.new
ps.each(&:quiet!)
workers = true
while workers
  works = []
  active_workers = Sidekiq::Workers.new.map do |_process_id, _thread_id, work|
    works = work
  end
  workers = works.length > 0
  if workers
    sleep 2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Dokku's zero-downtime deploy mechanism will wait a configurable amount of time before running `docker container stop`. This will send a `SIGTERM` to your application, and then a `SIGKILL` after a grace period.

Your application code should handle `SIGTERM` and gracefully stop accepting new work, finish old work, and then terminate. This is generally what background processing frameworks do by default, but you may need to configure this in yours or add the functionality if it is a custom framework you wrote.